# How to add NAMED SCOPES (or other declarations) to models of an installed gem (such as our Forem gem)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

**ENVIRONMENT**

ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]; Rails 3.2.6; OSX 10.6.8; devise (2.0.4); **forem-redcarpet (1.0.0)**

**OBJECTIVE**

We need to deploy additional order control in our Forem installation (gem). Likely, we will also want to declare further model attributes; and assumably, we would do this either:

1. **by appending named scopes** to underlying Forem models;
2. or **by overriding the underlying models**.

**QUESTION**

How would we do *either*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ANSWER ― HOW TO ACCOUNT FOR ABERRANT EXECUTION IN DECORATORS**

A colleague pointed my request to existing Forem documentation (**[Forem: Extending Classes](https://github.com/radar/forem#extending-classes)**), which **would** well answer this question, except for the following, **very probable** exceptions:

A reason I haven't responded until now, is that attempts to follow the recommended pattern were not initially successful, because *some* underlying code (a handful of exceptions) referred to model classes without prefacing them to belong to the Forem engine. Thus at first, it seemed this route didn't work at all; and, (I'm still not certain what all the ramifications are), **it seemed therefore to be necessary to override the underlying methods (which did not preface references with "Forem::") with revised references, in the form, "Forem::ModelName"** (as opposed to "ModelName").

As the Forem documentation page at Github indicates:

"All of Forem’s business logic (models, controllers, helpers, etc) can easily be extended / overridden to meet your exact requirements using standard Ruby idioms.

Standard practice for including such changes in your application or extension is to **create a directory app/decorators.** Place file within the relevant **app/decorators/models** or **app/decorators/controllers** directory, with **_decorator** appended to the original class name."

In other words, to assign further interface values in a controller process, you have to add a decorator to a respective directory from which Ruby will find and override the underlying process:

A controller from the original Forem source residing as /forem/app/ **controllers** /forem/admin/ **groups_controller.rb**, thus is overridden by /your_project_name/app/ **decorators** / **controllers** /forem/admin/ **groups_controller_decorator.rb**.

In the code snippet below (from this very file), you would regularly call "index_original", having aliased the original index method as "index_original":

```
Forem::Admin::GroupsController.class_eval do
alias_method :index_original, :index unless method_defined?(:index_original)

def index
    @h_title_of_page = t('h_title2_forum_admin_groups_index')
    @h_description2 = t('h_description2_forums')

    index_original 
    end
```

**This did not work however, because the underlying index method of the Forem controller makes the following assignment:**

```
@groups = Group.all
```

The call to "Group.all" thus precipitates in an error when you call index_original in your decorator, evidently because the ancestor isn't recognized without prefacing that it belongs to the Forem module:

```
@groups = Forem::Group.all
```

**Thus to fix this in your decorator, you are forced to take the following approach (# index_original is commented out to indicate what must replace it):**

```
def index
    @h_title_of_page = t('h_title2_forum_admin_groups_index')
    @h_description2 = t('h_description2_forums')

    # index_original
        @groups = Forem::Group.all # @groups = Group.all ERROR 
    end
```

Note that the statement "@groups = Forem::Group.all" is the only statement of the ancestor index method; thus bringing the fixed statement into your decorator is to bring the entire method code into your own decorator. This fixes the aberrant execution, only because this complete override of the ancestor index method is sufficient itself to eliminate any further calls to models which are not prefaced by Forem::. **If any further calls to underlying classes are not prefaced, those methods likewise must be brought into your decorator.**

**So, in order to account for every such potential aberration in your own (dependent) project,** you'll have to download the Forem source from Github, and research whether the underlying methods you must alias refer to their own models with/without prefacing them with "Forem::":

1. **If all called models called by the Forem process you are calling ARE prefaced**, then my efforts indicate you **can** alias a call to the original method (as index_original for example).
2. **BUT, IF ANY underlying call to Forem models in a process your decorator calls are NOT prefaced with "Forem::" on the other hand, my efforts indicate you MUST PULL ALL the code of the underlying methodS into your decorator (as above).**

Hopefully, in the future, either Ruby will recognize such references, and/or Forem authors will preface their references to their internals (even as the code should obviously run perfectly well otherwise, **in** the Forem development environment).

Comment: I've reported this issue to Forem authors at GitHub. Nonetheless, the answer applies to overriding the functionality of **any** installed gem/engine.

Answer (score 0):

Well...I ld suggest 1. (admittedly because I do have an answer for that ;-) )

Put this into your autoload_paths:

`extend_it.rb`:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ExtendIt
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :extension_scope, where(:name => "Mr. X")
  end

  module ClassMethods
  end
end
```

and something like this in an initializer:

`extend_it.rb`:

```
AnyClass.send :include, ExtendIt
```

Where of course `AnyClass` is one of your target classes. More reading can be found here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer and effort. This may indeed work, but I didn't try your solution because a colleague recommended I see Forem documentation which advocated a pattern which seems to more closely follow OOP patterns of overriding/subclassing ancestor classes.